# Build matrix with vectors resulting from indexed kronecker products without a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

Can I optimize the following code in Matlab by ditching the for loop?

```
A = [];
B = randn(4,8);
C = randn(8,4);
I = randperm(8,3);
J = randperm(8,3);
for i = 1:3
    A = [A kron(C(J(i),:)',B(:,I(i)))];
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, using the third dimension to store the intermediate results and transforming it back to 2D. This way you can also avoid `kron` itself which is not the fastest itself.

**Matlab R2016a or later:**

```
a = C(J,:).' .* permute(B(:,I),[3 2 1]);  %// calculation of the product to 3rd dimension
                                          %// by implicit expansion
b = permute( a, [3 1 2] );                %// permuting
out = reshape( b, [], 3 )                 %// reshape to desired form
```

short:

```
out = reshape( permute( C(J,:).' .* permute(B(:,I),[3 2 1]), [3 1 2] ), [], 3 )
```

**before Matlab R2016a:**

```
a = bsxfun(@times , C(J,:).', permute(B(:,I),[3 2 1])); %// calculation of 
                                          %// the product to 3rd dimension(explicit)
b = permute( a, [3 1 2] );                %// permuting
out = reshape( b, [], 3 )                 %// reshape to desired form
```

short:

```
out = reshape(permute(bsxfun(@times , C(J,:).', permute(B(:,I),[3 2 1])), [3 1 2] ), [], 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized version using `kron` (not as fast as [thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2605073/thewaywewalk) 's answer):

```
kron(C(J,:).', ones(size(B,1),1)) .* kron(ones(size(B,1),1), B(:,I))
```